# Pom.xml error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I have created a web project , and when i right click the `project->configure->maven` project, I get this error in `pom.xml`.

> Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4 from
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4 from/to
>   central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

Answer (score 8):

1 Goto the directory `{Home}/.m2/repository/org/apache`.

2  Delete the maven folder.
then  click the `project->configure->maven` project

To be more sure:-
    Right click on your Maven project in Eclipse and select `Maven -> Update Project`...

In the appeared dialog, select the Force Update of Snapshots/Releases and click OK

Make sure that, you do not have any proxy related problems when updating the project again.

Comment: This doesn't help in Eclipse 2024-03. A freshly created Maven project has pom.xml with tag <project> underlined in red. The error is: "Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'."

Answer (score 5):

Remove the troublesome library from your local repository manually (make it redownload). By default it's located in

> %USER%.m2\repository
>
> %USER%.m2\repository\org\apache\maven

Deleting the library from second location then rebuilding project usually fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Additionally,right click on the `pom.xml` file in the 'project explorer' > click on 'validate'. This should remove the red-error mark on file, if there are no problems in the XML configuration.

Comment: There is no such menu item in Eclipse 2024-03.

Answer (score -1):

Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/
 maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has 
 elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-
 plugin:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

IN C directory you can find ur m2repository location there u need to delete surefire 
goto user find m2 folder ->org->apache->surefire

ONCE delete this sure fire folder then update ur maven project.

rightclick->maven->upddateproject(check force update) NOW Error will be 
gone